# Scott on Zermelo set theory and Russell's theory of types

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I recall Dana Scott being attributed, or state the point of view that Zermelo set theory is justified by Russell's theory of types, but I failed to take notes.

May someone indicate where Scott stated, or were attributed this, and/or relate Scott's argument?

Comment: I think this might refer to his paper "Axiomatizing Set Theory."

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Do you know whether it is in volume 1 or 2 of T. Jech: Axiomatic Set Theory?

Comment: It is the second volume: [https://www.ams.org/books/pspum/013.2/](https://www.ams.org/books/pspum/013.2/)